# Why does my lighting look incorrect?

Tags: opengl, shader, lighting

[image: As you can see the back face is lighting as well]

I have a problem with lighting calculations.
I am rotating the camera around a cube which was supposed to be illuminated by the light but the resulting lighting is very weird.
Check out the image above, fragment shader and vertex shader below.

```
//Vertex shader

#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 norm;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform vec3 lightPos;


out vec3 ourNormal;
out vec3 fragPos;
out vec3 ourLightPos;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection*view*model*vec4(pos,1.0);
    fragPos = vec3(view * model * vec4(pos, 1.0f));
    ourNormal = mat3(transpose(inverse(view * model))) * norm;
    ourLightPos = vec3(view * vec4(lightPos, 1.0));
}



//fragment shader

#version 330 core

//Output variables
out vec4 finalColor;

//Input variables
in vec3 ourNormal;
in vec3 fragPos;
in vec3 ourLightPos;

//Uniform variables

struct Material
{
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
    float shininess;
};

struct Light
{
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};

uniform Light light;
uniform Material material;
uniform vec3 viewPos;

void main()
{
    //Ambient
    vec3 ambient = light.ambient*material.ambient;

    //Diffuse
    vec3 normal = normalize(ourNormal);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(ourLightPos - fragPos);
    float diffuseStrength = max(dot(lightDir,normal),0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = light.diffuse*(diffuseStrength*material.diffuse);

    //Specular
    vec3 viewDir = normalize(viewPos - fragPos);
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(-lightDir,normal);
    float specularStrength =         pow(max(dot(viewDir,reflectDir),0.0),material.shininess);
    vec3 specular = light.specular * (specularStrength*material.specular);

    //Last step
    vec3 result = (ambient+diffuse+specular);
    finalColor = vec4(result,1.0);
}
```

As you can see, I transformed all the positions, normals and light source position in view space, i.e camera space, but I don't know why it's not working.

Comment: Maybe your model of the box has a wrong normal.

Comment: This might not be the error, but you have a uniform "viewPos" which is, I assume, the camera position. But you do all calculations in Camera-Space, so this should always be $(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)$ and thereby the **viewDir** becomes $-1 * fragPos$.

Comment: @Dragonseel  Yup!! That was the problem! Thank you for taking out some time for this question!

Comment: @Dragonseel: since it was the correct observation, could you turn the comment into an answer?

Comment: @JulienGuertault yes. Done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your calculations is that you use a uniform for *viewPos* which is the camera position.
The rest of your calculations is in Camera-Space, so the *viewPos* should always be $(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)$ and thereby the $viewDir$ becomes $-1*\text{fragPos}$.

In general: Always be careful about the different reference frames your calculations can be done in and aim to keep this consistent.